# swing gui built at run time from NetBeans .form file

Tags: forms, user-interface, netbeans

It is possible to build at run time a swing gui directly from a NetBeans .form file? Someting like one can do with xml files generated by Glade to build GTK GUIs or with QtDesigner for Qt GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Maybe. Netbeans can recreate `.java`  files from `.form` files and since Netbeans is open source, something could be done, in theory.

In reality, I have not seen this functionality and I don't think it would be easy to accomplish. Some obstacles that come to my head are:

1. One must keep in mind that `.form` files don't preserve information about Java code that controls the behaviour of the interface, (Loading information, `Listener`'s definition and such).
2. In the default usage of Netbeans GUI builder, components are `private`  to the frame/dialog that cointains them. If we want to handle those componente from outside, the default `.form` -> `.java` creation would have to be altered.
3. Netbeans source code is huge and I would not expect it to be easy to split the required module.

**Alternative**

I'd take a look at [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm) and the [Java FX Scene Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/overview/jsbpub-overview.htm) to see if they fit your requirements since they have been created with the idea of splitting UI definition and logic.